# Python Multi-Threading use data from a thread in another thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm new to Python threading and what I'm trying to do is :

- 1 Thread with While loop that will execute a GET request to an API each N seconds to refresh the data
- A second Thread with a While loop that will use the data (ip addresses) to ping targets each N seconds.

So I was looking for a way to start the first Thread then only start the second after the first API call and then share these data to the second Thread so it can execute its logic.

Anyone can help me pls ? Thanks.

Comment: You should know ``threading`` and ``queue``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per you requirements, here is a simple boilerplate code you might want to try,

```
import time
import threading

available = False

def thread1():
    global available
    while True:
        # TODO: call API
        # --------------

        available = True # set available True after API call
        time.sleep(5) # perform API calls after every 5 seconds

def thread2():
    while True:
        # TODO: perform ping
        # --------------

        # perform ping request after every 5 seconds
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=thread1, name="thread1")
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=thread2, name="thread2")

    t1.start()

    while not available:
        time.sleep(0.1)
    else:
        t2.start()
```

Comment: I added a second global var to share result from API call and it works perfectly as expected, thanks !

Comment: Events are suited for this: `available = threading.Event()`.To set the event in your first function use `available.set()`.  Then instead of the while loop and sleep, you just use `available.wait()` which will wait until the available event is set.